# How to convert all float64 columns to float32 in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, dtype

Is there a generic way to convert all float64 values in a pandas dataframe to float32 values? But not changing uint16 to float32? I don't know the signal names in advance but just want to have no float64.

Something like:

```
if float64, then convert to float32, else nothing?
```

The structure of the data is:

```
DF.dtypes

Counter               uint16
p_007                 float64
p_006                 float64
p_005                 float64
p_004                 float64
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df.select_dtypes(np.float64).columns] = df.select_dtypes(np.float64).astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you

Answer (score 22):

1. If the dataframe (say `df`) wholly consists of `float64` dtypes, you can do:

```py
df = df.astype('float32')
```

2. Only if some columns are `float64`, then you'd have to select those columns and change their dtype:

```py
# Select columns with 'float64' dtype  
float64_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include='float64'))

# The same code again calling the columns
df[float64_cols] = df[float64_cols].astype('float32')
```

Comment: Why is select_dtypes() taking a while? does it scan through all rows...?